# Marker does not show up on map angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using angular-maps to create a map, with a list of markers.
I have a problem displaying the markers. I have no errors though.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('mapController', []);

app.service('Map', function($q) {

this.init = function() {
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.7154289, 4.9317724),
        zoom: 14,
        disableDefaultUI: true    
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), options
    );
    this.places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);


  var markers = [{
  "title": 'Capgemini',
  "lat": '45.7154289',
  "lng": '4.9317724',
  "description": 'Capgemini'

    }];
var defaultMarkerColor = 'ff0000';
      var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + defaultMarkerColor);

  // marker object for the marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat,markers[0].lng),
    map: this.map,
    title: markers[0].title,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: pinImage
  });
}

this.search = function(str) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    this.places.textSearch({query: str}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            d.resolve(results[0]);
        }
        else d.reject(status);
    });
    return d.promise;
}

this.addMarker = function(res) {
    if(this.marker) this.marker.setMap(null);
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        position: res.geometry.location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    this.map.setCenter(res.geometry.location);
}

});

app.controller('mapController', function($scope, Map) {

$scope.place = {};

$scope.search = function() {
    $scope.apiError = false;
    Map.search($scope.searchPlace)
    .then(
        function(res) { // success
            Map.addMarker(res);
            $scope.place.name = res.name;
            $scope.place.lat = res.geometry.location.lat();
            $scope.place.lng = res.geometry.location.lng();
        },
        function(status) { // error
            $scope.apiError = true;
            $scope.apiStatus = status;
        }
    );
}

$scope.send = function() {
    alert($scope.place.name + ' : ' + $scope.place.lat + ', ' + $scope.place.lng);    
}

Map.init();
});
```

and the **HTML** :

```
 <ion-content ng-controller="mapController" style="margin-top: 25px">

<div class="container">

<div id="map" libraries="places" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>


 <form name="searchForm" novalidate 
ng-submit="search()">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="place" type="text" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="searchPlace" required autofocus />
        <br>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" 
            ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

The map shows up correctly, and centered on the coordinates I chose, but without a marker.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi took me sometime to put in place the fiddle... :)

I made this changes to make it work:

The markers:

```
  var markers = [{
  "title": 'Capgemini',
  "lat": 45.7154289,
  "lng": 4.9317724,
  "description": 'Capgemini'
}];
```

And then the marker definition

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:{lat: markers[0].lat, lng: markers[0].lng},
    map: this.map,
    title: markers[0].title,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: pinImage
  });
```

the easiest way is to use numbers for the coords.

here you can find the [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rixlabs/fgk7e7ru/)
it isn't super clean and it is lot of debug stuff and most important if you can initialize and see the map you don't really need it.

hope this help